# How can I use AND , OR ... statements in an SQLITE sentence?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a problem trying to make a sqlite sentence, I'm simply trying to implement another condition in the sentence using a clasSical AND but it doesn't work anyway

```
Cursor row= bdd.rawQuery("select *  from ItemTable where id=1", null);// <---THAT WORKS

Cursor row= bdd.rawQuery("select *  from ItemTable where id=1 and country=us", null);// <---THAT does not work, and that's what I need
```

Other not-running tries

```
Cursor row= bdd.rawQuery("select *  from ItemTable where id=1 and country='us'", null);// <--Crush!

Cursor row= bdd.rawQuery("select *  from ItemTable where id=1 and country=\'us\'", null);// <--Crush!
```

With the first sentence program accesses perfectly to db an works fine, with the second sentence app crashes.

Can someone help me?

where can i find sqlite syntax rules or examples? I have read over there but there are only examples of simplest stuff.

Comment: sorry but it doesnt work , i have tested with -> country='us' and country=\'us\' but it doesnt, it crashes thanks anyway

Comment: You should learn about SQL placeholders, using string wrangling to build SQL is so 1998 (and it was a terrible idea even back then). What is the exact error message you get when it crashes?

Comment: So im emulating with bluestacks how can I see the error

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround the string by single quotes.

```
Cursor row= bdd.rawQuery("select * from ItemTable where id=1 and country='us'", null);
```

For non-string columns (e.g. integer columns), you don't need single quotes.

Comment: both id and country or its because country is an string?

Comment: only `country` because it is a string

Comment: Sorry but like this too, app crashes.                             {sorry but it doesnt work , i have tested with -> country='us' and country=\'us\' but it doesnt, it crashes thanks anyway –  u}

Comment: i dont know because Im emaulating with bluestacks, i thing its the fastest way to emulate apk apps, because with eclipses emulators is impossible. sorry

Comment: too little information to debug. The crash cause may not even in this line.